# ReactJS Griddle override inline style

Tags: css, reactjs, griddle

I am creating an application and I am using the ReactJS Griddle component.  I am trying to create a custom row component but it keep applying an inline style like so:

```
<div class="myCustomRowClass" data-reactid="react_id" style="clear:both;display:table;width:100%">
```

I would need to override the style so I can set `display: grid;`.  The reason for this is that I am using Semantic-Ui for the user interface, and when I do something like this:

```
<div class="ui four cards">
   <div class="ui card">
     /* content */
   </div>
   <div class="ui card">
     /* content */
   </div>
   /* etc... */
</div>
```

instead of display a grid of 4 card per row, it displays one card per row.

Is there a way I can override the style?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to this.  I should have used `customGridComponent` instead of `customRowComponent` and render my data in the `CustomGridComponent`